# how to dynamically center image (Website banner)

Tags: css

I currently have a site [rinique.com](http://rinique.com/). The website banner that I wish to dynamically center is the image with the word "RINIQUE" based on screen size (eg. iphone and ipad).

Currently to make it center, I had put in a absolute value. Below is a snippet of my css.

```
#header #logo {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 38%;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use javascript if you could use simple CSS ?

```
#logo {
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

}

Just make the a#logo behave as a block element, and align it's content IMG center.

http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/N9XtP/

Comment: +1 from me. best and easiest solution :) and I like your avatar

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
    margin: auto; /* this requires the element to be block-level with a set dimension (i.e., not width: auto) */
    width: 300px; /* or whatever width your asset is */
    display: block; /* <a/> elements are inline by default */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that css entry and add this one.

```
#logo > img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something along the lines of this snippet of jQuery:

```
    $('#logo').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2)) + "px");
    $('#logo').css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2)) + "px");
```

Comment: I thought he also wanted to center vertically and this was the easiest way I could think of achieving that.

Comment: jQuery is overkill for this, a simple CSS change will make it work, as mentioned in various answers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the css solution suggestion by other will be good enough for me